# Query doesn't give exact result

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, select

My query doesn't give me a correct result when i code it in the Visual Studio, but when I try it in the MySql Workbench, it works fine. Can someone help me?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = null;
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost; port=3306;username=root;password=; database = cmb;");

string se = "SELECT date AS 'Date', COUNT(case when patienttype = 'Child' then 1 else null end) AS `No of Child`, COUNT(case when patienttype = 'Adult' then 1 else null end) AS `No of Adult` FROM cmb.stat";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(se, mycon);

mycon.Open();
using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    da.Fill(dataTable);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
dataGridView1.DataMember = dataTable.TableName;
mycon.Close();
```

Result in VS Studio:

[image: Result in VS Studio]

Result in MySQL Workbench:

[image: Result in MySql Workbench]

Comment: The query is wrong and I have no idea how the mysqlworkbench could possibly return those results unless it somehow is inferring a grouping clause..... Please provide the table schema.

Comment: please post the exact query used by the MySql Workbench and the table schema.

Comment: Seems like you omitted a `group by date` in the c# code.

Comment: SELECT date AS 'Date', COUNT(case when patienttype = 'Child' then 1 else null end) AS `No of Child`, COUNT(case when patienttype = 'Adult' then 1 else null end) AS `No of Adult` FROM cmb.stat GROUP BY `date`

Comment: That what my codes now. And still, it doesn't give the correct result

Comment: It's working now.